# Saving textbox text into XML file

Tags: c#, .net, web, webforms

I have an ASP.NET WebForm with 1 button and 4 textboxes.

Every time the page loads, the following code to read data from an XML file and display in the textboxes is executed:

```
private void PutWhatWasBefore()
{
    var xml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Settings.xml");

    From_display.Text = xml.Element("Settings").Element("Remember").Attribute("fromdisplay").Value.ToString();
    From_Smtp.Text = xml.Element("Settings").Element("Remember").Attribute("fromsmtp").Value.ToString();
    subject.Text = xml.Element("Settings").Element("Remember").Attribute("subject").Value.ToString();     
}
```

This code works well, it puts everything in the textboxes. BUT, and this is a big but, when i click the button, the following code to write to the XML file does not work:

```
string tem = Template1.Text;
string from = From_Smtp.Text;
string dis = From_display.Text;
string sub = subject.Text;
var x = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Settings",
        new XElement("Remember",
            new XAttribute("fromsmtp", from),
            new XAttribute("subject", sub),
            new XAttribute("fromdisplay", dis),
            new XAttribute("template", tem)
        )
    )
);
x.Save(@"C:\Settings.xml");
```

No matter how I change the data in the text boxes, every time I click on the button the data reverts back to what it was before.

I was thinking its a post back and that's why this is happening, but even if i disable the post back with `OnClientClick = return false;` it still does not work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT(12:06):**

I don't think I have said where the problem was and I want to be more into the point.

When I click the button the following function is executed first:

```
private void SaveNames()
{
    try
    {
        string tem = Template1.Text;
        string from = From_Smtp.Text;
        string dis = From_display.Text;
        string sub = subject.Text;
        var x = new XDocument(
            new XElement("Settings",
                new XElement("Remember",
                    new XAttribute("fromsmtp", "He2"),
                    new XAttribute("subject", sub),
                    new XAttribute("fromdisplay", dis),
                    new XAttribute("template", tem)
                )
            )
        );
        x.Save(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\ActivePath\MailSenderWeb\Settings.xml");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AnswerAndError.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

That's the functions that doesn't work. It just doesn't save new data into the XML file.

Comment: +1 'and this is a big but'

Comment: I tried your code using WinForms and it is working perfectly fine. Are you using ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes i am , asp.net. webfroms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your issue:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        PutWhatWasBefore();
    }
}
```

This will ensure the code runs only when the page is initially visited.

Comment: I am not having any problems with the putwhatwasbefore functions, i amm having a problem with the save into the xml functions

Comment: I understand that. The problem is when you click the button, the page gets refreshed, triggering the code in PutWhatWasBefore() function, which refreshes your text boxes from the XML file. Using the Page.IsPostBack property will ensure the button click does not execute the function, thereby updating the XML file with the new values.

Comment: If i using if (Page.IsPostBack == false) is works, thanks alot. have a good day.

Comment: Lol, that is strange. Thanks for sharing anyways.