# css is lost on postback

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, postback

I currently have a problem with my website in ASP.net / C#. I'm building a page, where a couple of elements are dependent on others. On this page I use some import css classes, though they seem to get lost, whenever a Postback happens. Could anyone take a look at the code and tell me where it goes wrong?

I used a .NET fiddle file to paste the code of my .ascx and .ascx.cs file. I hope it's somewhat clear. Apologies if it's not.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/NLwtiN

EDIT: I tried to compare the html of 2 DropDownLists, hoping there'd be some significant difference, though there is next to none

[image]

Comment: A user whose [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238057/saving-textbox-text-into-xml-file/25239273#25239273) I just answered told me that if (!Page.IsPostBack) did not work for him, however if (Page.IsPostBack == false) worked. Maybe you can try it out, just in case.

Comment: mhm I tried that, but there's no difference. The css still doesn't load after the PB, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Is the only "selected" attribute on the `<option>` element the only difference during postback - is this the CSS issue?